# Is there any diff between the results of the following tables?

Tags: sql, coding-style

Basic information:[Ollivander's Inventory from Hacker rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/harry-potter-and-wands/problem)

is there any diff between

```
SELECT code, power, MIN(coins_needed) AS coins_needed
FROM Wands
GROUP BY code, power
```

and

```
SELECT code, m.power, m.coins_needed
 FROM (SELECT code, power, MIN(coins_needed) AS coins_needed 
       FROM Wands
       GROUP BY code, power
      ) AS m JOIN 
      Wands AS w
     ON m.code = w.code AND m.power = w.power AND 
        m.coins_needed = w.coins_needed
```

and why we need to join the original table itself to get the right result?
I tried to use Product table from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_min), it returns the same result except the order of data.

Comment: in this case, think you do not need to join with the original table, first query is enough.

Comment: will be diff in other cases?

Comment: in case if you want to select all the rows from wands with minimum coins_needed. You can find the min coins_needed and self join with original table (without the code in the join).

Comment: The 2 queries are different. `min` will return you one row with the minimum value on each group, by joininng on this back to the same table you will be getting all rows that share that value, if more than one. What you do depends on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the two queries *look* different and would probably generate different execution plans.  The queries also *are* different.

The most important difference is that the first query returns one row for each unique combination of `code` and `power` int he database.

The second query will return duplicates if there are two rows that have the same minimum values.  In other words, it returns all *rows* in the original data that have the minimum number of coins for each `code`/`power` combination.

A more subtle difference is how `NULL` values are treated.  The first query returns `NULL` values for `code` and `power`.  The second filters out the `NULL` values.

The two queries should return the same results if `code` and `power` have no `NULL` values and if `coins_needed` is unique on rows with the same `code` and `power`.  However, those are big assumptions and the queries are not equivalent.

Note that window functions are a simpler way to write the second query:

```
SELECT code, power, coins_needed
FROM (SELECT w.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY code, power ORDER BY coins_needed) as seqnum
      FROM Wands w
     ) w
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Well, this is not 100% equivalent because it includes `NULL` values for `code` and `power`.